# Removal of a node while keeping the connectivty

Tags: graph-theory

This is a vocabulary question, Is there a specific name for the removal of a node in a directed graph while keeping the strong connectivity of other nodes un-changed. An edge is added between every combination predecessors and successors nodes to keep the connectivity.

I'm pretty sure that there is one, but I did not find it.

Thanks for your help,
Alexis

Answer (score 0):

This is called **bipartite (network)** or **multimodal projection** according to [this MO answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/255992).

If the node involved (`v`) has degrees `indeg(v) = 1 = outdeg(v)`, it is also called **smoothing**.

For the sake of completeness, with nodes having no inarcs or no outarcs it is  of course **node deletion**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however if anyone may provide a link to a reference book/paper as none was provided on the given answer it would be appreciated.

Comment: This paper discusses bipartite projection: [Tao Zhou et al.: Bipartite network projection and personal recommendation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5851936_Bipartite_network_projection_and_personal_recommendation)